# HTML CSS automatically adjust height

Tags: html, css, angularjs, less

I am trying to display outbound and inbound flight by visualising it using CSS/LESS. The problem is that when Outbound flight has more airport changes then Inbound then line stays at the level of first flight. I want line adjust height dynamically based on the longest route.

Could you please help me to figure out how do achieve required results?

**UPDATE**: Prepared [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XLXnnXXYPtC4c50b7Hj6?p=preview) example (make a screen wider in order to see it properly)

This is what I've got:

[image]

This is what I am trying achive:

[image]

LESS:

```
.time-slice {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: stretch;
  -webkit-align-items: stretch;
  -ms-flex-align: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.time-slice > * {
  padding: 20px;
}

.circle {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  border-color: #29a8bb;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 32px;
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
.circle-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 91px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.circle-wrap > .circle {
  position: relative;
  left: 20px;
}
.date-time {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
  -ms-flex-negative: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  -webkit-flex-basis: 100px;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 100px;
  flex-basis: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -5px;
}
.date,
.time {
  max-width: 90px;
  color: #999999;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}


.time-slice.row:not(:last-child) .point-title {
  border-left: 2px solid blue;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
}


.duration {
  margin-left: 50px;
  max-width: 90px;
  color: #999999;
  font-size: 13px;

  margin-bottom: 10px;
}




.stop-transit {
  border-width: 2px;
  color: red;
  padding-left: 5px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.stop-transit, .transit-path, .wait-time{
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.transit-path {
  border-right-style:dotted;
  width: 140px;
}


.wait-reason{
  text-align: center;
}

.searchResult{
  padding: 0px 15px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="{{ticket.id}}" style="display:none">
            <div class="col-md-6 line">
                <h3>OUTBOUND</h3>
                <div ng-repeat="departureFlight in ticket.route.departureFlights">

                    <div class="timeline">
                        <div class="time-slice row">
                            <div class="date-time">
                                <p class="date">{{departureFlight.departureTime | date:"EEE d MMM"}}</p>
                                <p class="time">{{departureFlight.departureTime | date:"h:mma"}}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="circle-wrap">
                                <div class="circle"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="point-title">
                                <span>
                                    <b>{{departureFlight.cityFrom}} ({{departureFlight.flyFrom}})</b>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="time-slice row">
                            <div class="date-time">
                                <p class="time duration">{{departureFlight.arrivalTime-departureFlight.departureTime | date:"h:mm"}}h</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="point-title">
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="time-slice row">
                            <div class="date-time">
                                <p class="date">{{departureFlight.arrivalTime | date:"EEE d MMM"}}</p>
                                <p class="time">{{departureFlight.arrivalTime | date:"h:mma"}}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="circle-wrap">
                                <div class="circle"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="point-title">
                                <span>
                                    <b>{{departureFlight.cityTo}} ({{departureFlight.flyTo}})</b>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div ng-if="departureFlight.transferFlight">
                        <table class="stop-transit">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="transit-path">
                                    <div class="wait-reason">Connection change<br>
                                        Long wait &nbsp;<span class="glyphicons glyphicons-airplane">✈</span></div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="wait-time">{{departureFlight.departureTime | date:"h:mm"}} hours</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h3>INBOUND</h3>
                <div ng-repeat="returnFlight in ticket.route.returnFlights">

                    <div class="timeline">
                        <div class="time-slice row">
                            <div class="date-time">
                                <p class="date">{{returnFlight.departureTime | date:"EEE d MMM"}}</p>
                                <p class="time">{{returnFlight.departureTime | date:"h:mma"}}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="circle-wrap">
                                <div class="circle"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="point-title">
                            <span>
                                <b>{{returnFlight.cityFrom}} ({{returnFlight.flyFrom}})</b>
                            </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="time-slice row">
                            <div class="date-time">
                                <p class="time duration">{{returnFlight.arrivalTime-returnFlight.departureTime | date:"h:mm"}}h</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="point-title">
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="time-slice row">
                            <div class="date-time">
                                <p class="date">{{returnFlight.arrivalTime | date:"EEE d MMM"}}</p>
                                <p class="time">{{returnFlight.arrivalTime | date:"h:mma"}}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="circle-wrap">
                                <div class="circle"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="point-title">
                            <span>
                                <b>{{returnFlight.cityTo}} ({{returnFlight.flyTo}})</b>
                            </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div ng-if="returnFlight.transferFlight">
                        <table class="stop-transit">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="transit-path">
                                    <div class="wait-reason">Connection change<br>
                                        Long wait &nbsp;<span class="glyphicons glyphicons-airplane">✈</span></div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="wait-time">{{returnFlight.departureTime | date:"h:mm"}} hours</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Hi. Do you have a working snippet or fiddle somewhere?

Comment: I will try to prepare, just a sec.

Comment: @PraveenKumar, I have prepared plunker example. http://plnkr.co/edit/XLXnnXXYPtC4c50b7Hj6?p=preview

Comment: @WildGoat the code in the question, as well as the plunker go well beyond the requirement of showing what you have and what you need. Angular is not a part of the question here, HTML / CSS is. That just creates a huge smoke screen between what you need and what you ask.

Comment: @Amit, first of all thank you very much for your answer below. I've just created a plunker to demonstrate my HTML/CSS problem, no changes required in .js.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That just screams flexbox. [Support level](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) is already at 94.82%. You will need to use all those ugly prefixes, but you can help yourself with STYLUS/LESS and the rest of 'em.

Here's a quick outline of what you might end up with:

```css
.roundtrip {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
  background-color: #909090;
}

.trip {
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0px 3px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flight {
  background-color: #B0B0B0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.flight-path {
  width: 6px;
  min-height: 15px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  align-self: center;
  background-color: #6090FF;
}

.connection {
  height: 40px;
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<span class="roundtrip">
  <div class="trip">Outbound
    <div class="flight">Los Angeles</div>
    <div class="flight-path"></div>
    <div class="flight">Chicago</div>
    <div class="connection">5hr wait</div>
    <div class="flight">Chicago</div>
    <div class="flight-path"></div>
    <div class="flight">New York</div>
    <div class="connection">2hr wait</div>
    <div class="flight">New York</div>
    <div class="flight-path"></div>
    <div class="flight">Amsterdam</div>
  </div>
  <div class="trip">Inbound
    <div class="flight">Amsterdam</div>
    <div class="flight-path"></div>
    <div class="flight">Los Angeles</div>
  </div>
</span>
```

Comment: Amit, thank you very much for your answer it looks very expressive, I like it. I might be very simple here since I am not a CSS/LESS expert but do you think refactoring my solution above, using your the way you have demonstrated might be quite problematic? What should I start looking at first?

Comment: I had a look at the plunker you posted and it's really hard to tell exactly what's "wrong" there since there's too much markup to sift. I think you have some elements that are `display: block` and would benefit from being flexboxes as well. I'd start with a cleaner slate (You can use my fragment if you'd like), and slowly add features (UI elements) and see what breaks your design flow. Hopefully either nothing will, or at least you'll be able to pin point the problem and solve it (Or come to SO again :-)

Comment: This is awesome! `:)`

Comment: @Amit, how can I split inbound/outbound in separate bootstrap columns 6 by 6? Then I do so, Inbound it out of sync with outbound by height... thanks!

Comment: @Amit, I've integrated your solution into my code unfortunately I faced similar issue which I had when I posted current question. Could you please take a look at my question again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32541364/need-html-css-alignment-solution