# Need HTML CSS alignment solution

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, less

I am really not sure if I am on the right path... every time I find solution for my previous problem and later on when I integrate "fixed" code with something else it breaks again, so that made me think that I am doing something fundamentally wrong here. Thats why I am asking you to REVIEW and propose FIX or completele new SOLUTION for something that I plan to achieve.

I am trying to display a flight information and each route should be displayed the way you see on the picture.

Right now, it works but in some cases when Outbound flight has more connections than Inbound flight, flight path (blue line) gets interrupted and stays on the same level as second flight in the Outbound. I want in current scenario, blue path go all the way down and each Inbound/Outbound flight path length must be in sync and in respect to each other. (same length no matter how many connections each flight has)

Could you please help me to figure out, how do I fix or change entire architecture, solution, CSS, to draw a blue path line and keep Inbound and Outbound flights the same length no matter how many connections each of these has?

[Plunker code example](http://plnkr.co/edit/nS6hnIAYWrv5kIGFf2CW?p=preview)

[image]

HTML:

```
    <div class="roundtrip">
        <div class="col-md-6">Outbound

            <div class="trip" ng-repeat="departureFlight in ticket.route.departureFlights">

                <div class="flight align-bottom">
                    <div class="date-time col-md-offset-2 col-md-3">
                        <div class="flight-time">{{departureFlight.departureTime | date:"h:mma"}}</div>
                        <div class="flight-date">{{departureFlight.departureTime | date:"EEE, MMM d, y"}}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-offset-0 col-md-2">{{departureFlight.cityFrom}} ({{departureFlight.flyFrom}})</div>
                </div>


                <div class="flight-path">
                    <div class="flight-path">
                        <div class="flight-duration">{{departureFlight.arrivalTime-departureFlight.departureTime | date:"h:mm"}}hr</div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="flight align-bottom">
                    <div class="date-time col-md-offset-2 col-md-3">
                        <div class="flight-time">{{departureFlight.arrivalTime | date:"h:mma"}}</div>
                        <div class="flight-date">{{departureFlight.arrivalTime | date:"EEE, MMM d, y"}}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-offset-0 col-md-2">{{departureFlight.cityTo}} ({{departureFlight.flyTo}})</div>
                </div>

                <div class="connection" ng-if="departureFlight.transferFlight">
                   {{departureFlight.arrivalTime | date:"h:mm"}}hr wait
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">Inbound

            <div class="trip" ng-repeat="returnFlight in ticket.route.returnFlights">

                <div class="flight align-bottom">
                    <div class="date-time col-md-offset-2 col-md-3">
                        <div class="flight-time">{{returnFlight.departureTime | date:"h:mma"}}</div>
                        <div class="flight-date">{{returnFlight.departureTime | date:"EEE, MMM d, y"}}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-offset-0 col-md-2">{{returnFlight.cityFrom}} ({{returnFlight.flyFrom}})</div>
                </div>


                <div class="flight-path">
                    <div class="flight-path">
                        <div class="flight-duration">{{returnFlight.arrivalTime-returnFlight.departureTime | date:"h:mm"}}hr</div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="flight align-bottom">
                    <div class="date-time col-md-offset-2 col-md-3">
                        <div class="flight-time">{{returnFlight.arrivalTime | date:"h:mma"}}</div>
                        <div class="flight-date">{{returnFlight.arrivalTime | date:"EEE, MMM d, y"}}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-offset-0 col-md-2">{{returnFlight.cityTo}} ({{returnFlight.flyTo}})</div>
                </div>

                <div class="connection" ng-if="returnFlight.transferFlight">
                    {{returnFlight.arrivalTime | date:"h:mm"}}hr wait
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.searchResult {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.align-bottom {  /*added*/
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
.roundtrip {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.trip {
  //width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.flight {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.date-time {
  text-align: center;
}
.flight-path {
  position: relative;
  width: 6px;
  min-height: 135px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  align-self: center;
  background-color: #6090FF;
}

.flight-duration {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
  text-align: center;
  left:-15px;
}

.connection {
  height: 40px;
  align-self: center;
  width: 70px;
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example where the error occurs? The one I see at http://plnkr.co/edit/nS6hnIAYWrv5kIGFf2CW?p=preview looks fine ...

Comment: @StefanBraun, there are no errors. My problem is that flight path (blue line) length of Inbound flight is not the same length as Outbound flight. In other words if return flight has zero or less connections than outbound flight line should be longer. Length of line for both flights should be exactly the same no matter how many connections are there.

Comment: @WildGoat - How is this different from your [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32427780/html-css-automatically-adjust-height), and why are you again posting a question that is not [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? The angular part is confusing, it's making it hard to analyze and contributes nothing to the question.

Comment: @Amit, angular part is only thing that breaks it everything here. I am using code that you have given and it works fine, but as soon as I use `ng-repeat`  to construct html it breaks everything. So I though someone might have an idea how to integrate current solution with angular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't follow [my original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32428183/3887516), you again inserted block elements where they shouldn't be and thus broke the flexbox.

See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pgC4lkAqWw74GLFtUBj0?p=preview), using angular's `ng-repeat-start/end` to remove unnecessary `<div>`s and not breaking the flexbox.

The key change is in:

```
<div class="col-md-6 trip">Outbound
   <div class="flight align-bottom"
    ng-repeat-start="departureFlight in ticket.route.departureFlights">
```

Comment: Thanks!!! Works! You very helpful Amit, I've discovered something new for myself.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you add a class for both outbound and inbound, say `split2` (for 2 in a column) and `split3` (for 3 in a column). Then you give every .trip a relative height. 33% for `.split3 .trip` and 50% for `.split2 .trip`.

Although just a quick sketch, i hope you get the idea: http://plnkr.co/edit/Edj0BuPRWMCn6c74d0C3?p=info

Comment: As I can understand you suggest hardcode a class. Unfortunately I want to make it completely dynamic since it might be 5 connections or a direct flight.

Comment: A little JS might help but I admit it's not very elegant. But the only solution I know is working.